# Android BitmapLimit: over bitmap size limit

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I use setImageResource() to set background image to ImageView.

My device resolution is 1920x2246 480dpi, so I find a image which resolution is the same as the device. But I got this warning:

> BitmapLimit: over bitmap size limit:android.graphics.Bitmap@6aad1ab, w
>   = 1080, h = 2246, size = 9702752

Then I crop this image to 1920x923, but I still got this warning

> BitmapLimit: over bitmap size limit:android.graphics.Bitmap@6aad1ab, w
>   = 923, h = 1920, size = 7088672

I cannot google any information about this warning.

My image is put at drawable/xxhdip and I use android studio plugin "Android Drawable Import" to import and crop hdip, mdip and xhdip automatic.

I will be grateful if anyone can give me some advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its about size of image not height and width.
You can compress this image to solve this problem

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("1024x768.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

Log.e("Original   dimensions", original.getWidth()+" "+original.getHeight());
Log.e("Compressed dimensions", decoded.getWidth()+" "+decoded.getHeight());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's strange that compress PNG, 100 means no compress, right? Why I set decoded bitmap to imageview is working?